# rails simple_form submit button with confirm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, confirm

I'm working in Rails 4 using simple_form and using wicked to create a wizard.

I have a button that works great:

```
<%= f.button :button, "<i class='fa fa-chevron-right btn-next'></i>".html_safe, data: {disable_with: "<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-2x'></i>"} %>
```

But for one of the steps I'd like to add a popup like this (which also works):

```
<%= f.submit :button, data: {confirm: "Are you sure this information is correct?"} %>
```

However, I can't figure out how to get them both together, something like this:

```
<%= f.button :button, "<i class='fa fa-chevron-right btn-next'></i>".html_safe, data: { confirm: "Are you sure this information is correct?", disable_with: "<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-2x'></i>"} %>
```

This ends up doing 2 popups and then doesn't submit anything and stays on the same page.

Any ideas?  Thanks!!

Comment: have you considered using the javascript approach? listen to the submit and do a confirmation popup

Comment: sorry i'm pretty terrible in js, so not sure what that entails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out this was a problem with the jquery-rails gem.

https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails/issues/173

In my gem file, I changed from this:
gem 'jquery-rails'

To this:
gem 'jquery-rails',  '~> 3.0'

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.submit-button').on("click", function() {
    if (confirm('Are you sure ?')) {
        $(".form-vertical").submit();
    }
})

<%= f.button :button, "<i class='fa fa-chevron-right btn-next'></i>".html_safe, data: {disable_with: "<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-2x'></i>"}, class: 'submit-button' %>
```

Comment: Thanks, something still isn't right and the popup is not being triggered. I put the JS in my application.js file, and replaced the form-id '<%= simple_form_for @user, url: wizard_path, html: {class: "form-vertical", method: :put, id: :name_dob_country_form} do |f| %>'

Comment: @bft check updated code..have you done the changes as I have done

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work when I substitute your code for the button on my existing simple_form code. Hmm can you post the code for the simple_form?

Comment: here's what I had in the top of my simple_form: '<%= simple_form_for @user, url: wizard_path, html: {class: "form-vertical", method: :put} do |f| %>'

Comment: Your code seems fine. What can you see in the logs when confirming the alert message?

Comment: Started GET "/account_setups/name_dob_country" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-16 18:20:40 +0700
Processing by AccountSetupsController#show as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"name_dob_country"}

Comment: It seems it is not reaching your server. Can you please try debugger in your Browser( f12 ) and check the console or network tab and post the logs here? Thanks!